# solving linear first order ODEs (inhomogeneous case)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

am currently studying an example of first order ODEs but for an inhomogeneous case:
(dx/dt) + r(t)x = g(t).

1st step: multiply both sides by integrating factor, e^(∫r(t) dt).
we then obtain
d/dt (xe^(∫r(t) dt)) =e^(∫r(t) dt)g(t).
I cant proceed further .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating both sides gives you

$$xe^{\int r(t) dt}=\int e^{\int r(t)dt} g(t) dt$$

It then depends on the functions $r(t)$ and $g(t)$ to proceed.

Comment: the worked example says: integrate both sides and divide throughout by e^(∫r(t) dt) to yield : x(t) = [ { e^ -(∫r(t) dt) } ∫(g(t)e^(∫r(t) dt) dt ) ] + Ae^-(∫r(t) dt. but i cannot understand the workings.

Comment: Yes, since the right hand side is an indefinite integral, it includes a constant $A$ in it. So when you divide by $e^{\int r(t) dt}$, or equivalently, multiply by $e^{-\int r(t) dt}$, that is what you get.

Comment: yess makes sense. thank you